# Arc Length Of Parametric Curve

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric

I attached the problem as a file:
$$x=e^{-t} \cos t, \, y= e^{-t} \sin t, \, 0 \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}= -e^{-t}(\sin t + \cos t), \, \frac{dy}{dt} = e^{-t}(\cos t - \sin t)$$
\begin{align*}
s & = \int_0^{\pi / 2} \sqrt{\left ( \frac{dx}{dt} \right ) ^2 +  \left ( \frac{dy}{dt} \right )^2} \, dt\\
& = \int_0^{\pi / 2} \sqrt{2e^{-2t}} \, dt = - \sqrt{2} \int_0^{\pi / 2} e^{-t}(-1) \, dt\\
& \phantom{= \int_0^{\pi / 2} \sqrt{2e^{-2t}} \, dt \,} = \left [ - \sqrt{2}e^{-t} \right ]_0^{\pi / 2}\\
& \phantom{= \int_0^{\pi / 2} \sqrt{2e^{-2t}} \, dt \,} = \sqrt{2} (1 - e^{-\pi / 2}) \approx 1.12
\end{align*}

Where did the trig functions go? I sifted through the different trig identities and formulas, but couldn't find anything that I could use. What should I do?

Comment: $\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t=1$ for any $t$.

Comment: Oh, they just factored out $e^{-2t}$, and then combined the trig terms together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
& (\sin(t)+\cos(t))^2+(\sin(t)-\cos(t))^2
\\ & = \sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)+2\cos(t)\sin(t)+\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)-2\cos(t)\sin(t)
\\ & =2(\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t))
\\ & =2
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you perhaps use latex?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much!!